# Семафоры в Linux

Tags: семафоры, c++, linux

Здравствуйте!

Решаю задачу синхронизации процессов в Linux.

**Задача первая** и главная. Есть два/три процесса, все они получают одни и те же сообщения, примерно одновременно. Один из этих процессов, давайте называть ведущим, остальные - ведомыми. Необходимо при получении одного, из всего изобилия сообщений, ведущим процессом устанавливать **некоторые** значения для ведомых, ведомые же приостанавливать до окончания записи этих значений. А после, на ведомых, делать выбор между запуском функции обработки сообщения или продолжением работы без обработки.

Т.е. это похоже на очередь с "буфером" равным 1 или 2 (в зависимости от количества ведомых процессов). Причем ведущий процесс ничего не обрабатывает, а лишь, выдает команды, основываясь на знании того, сколько ведомых процессов в данный момент заняты обработкой: отдать 1му, отдать 2му, сбросить. Прелесть такого способа хороша, когда необходимо знать, сколько сообщений было отброшено (ведь процесс не имеет возможности слушать сообщения во время обработки).

В данном случае, семафоры хотелось бы использовать для организации блокировки (т.е. ожидания готовности данных, **но не более**), а так же для передачи этих самых данных. Под данными я подразумеваю счетчик, определяющий сколько процессов свободны, и какие из них свободны (например двухбитный флаг).

---

**Вторая задача** - это упразднение ведущего процесса. Теперь все процессы равнозначны по задачам. Это дает выигрыш в обработке, так как третий процесс может быть задействован. Но здесь возникает вопрос, как синхронизировать процессы, чтобы не дать двум и более процессам обрабатывать одно и то же сообщение.

Для решения этой задачи я бы использовал все те же семафоры, позволяющие "следить" за счетчиком процессов, и, теперь уже, трехбитный флаг, который решает теперь две задачи: задачу выбора обрабатывающего процесса, по старшинству нулевого бита, и задачу идентификации свободных процессов.

---

Но, столкнулся с трудностями, не могу до конца осознать необходимые действия после получения идентификатора семафора в Linux. Пользуясь возможностями `ftok`, получаю уникальный ключ к своему семафору. Далее через `sem_get` получаю сам семафор или его создаю.

А дальше куда глядеть? Есть адекватное описание функций для реализации того, что мне нужно (развернутое описание того, что функция делает, какие параметры и каких типов принимает, что возвращает)? Не откажусь и от направления мыслей в области решения второй задачи. Все еще усугубляется тем, что блокировка процессов должна быть минимальной, любые задержки чреваты. Код должен быть легким, оптимальным и быстрым.

Comment: А как процессы получают эти сообщения? Это что, сигналы или данные в сокет?

Comment: Скажем, что это черный ящик. У нас есть код, который следует уже после получения данного сообщения. Поэтому и стоит задача - заблокировать ведомые процессы до получения "команды" от ведущего.

Comment: Т.е. сообщение получено (скажем ведущим) и он (видимо через shared memory) должен его передать любому свободному (ждущему на семафоре)?

Comment: Нет, все сообщения видны всеми процессами. Нужно лишь разрешить его обработку одному из процессов.

Comment: Навскидку, для разделения ресурсов Вам надо использовать pthread_mutex_t, pthread_cond_t и соответствующие вызовы с ними в shared_memory, возможно наряду с семафорами.

Очередь через pthread_cond удобно организовывать.

Comment: Дело в том что если я все правильно понял это можно реализовать с помощью семафоров без чего-либо еще. Данные, расшариваемые между процессами составляют всего два байта. Вот меня и интересует описание функций и небольшой алгоритм реализации необходимого функционала.

Comment: Наверное можно. Среди ночи не соображу.

Answer (score 1):

Начну с терминологии: ведущему процессу хорошо подойдет имя диспетчер, а всем остальным - обработчики.

Так вот, я бы создавал бы у каждого обработчика свою очередь. Туда можно писать указатели на обрабатываемые данные, либо индекс.

В результате проблем с синхронизацией не будет в принципе.

Диспетчер вычитывает входящую, "перекладывает" работу на обработчики и следит за скоростью их работы.